# Spanning a squareGrid with turf over the whole map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, turfjs

I am using turf to create a `squareGrid`:

```js
var Karte = L.map('Karte').setView([34.724126, -92.4079673], 15);  
         L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
         'attribution':  'Kartendaten &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> Mitwirkende',
         'useCache': true
         }).addTo(Karte);      

        var bbox = [-95, 30 ,-85, 40];
                var cellSide = 5;
                var options = {units: 'kilometers'};

                var squareGrid = turf.squareGrid(bbox, cellSide, options);
        
        
                L.geoJSON(squareGrid).addTo(Karte);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@turf/turf@6.5.0/turf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/papaparse@5.3.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


 <div id='Karte' style='height: 800px; width: 100%;'></div>
```

As you can see the bbox spans only over a certain segment of the map. I would like to span it over the whole provided map. (openstreetmap)

Any suggestions how to do this?

I appreciate your replies.

Comment: Fake it. Rebuild the grid whenever the map's center changes.

Comment: @IvanSanchez Can you provide an example? Thx in advance!

Comment: Maybe is https://github.com/cloudybay/leaflet.latlng-graticule what you want